# Complex third order PDE

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a two dimensional strictly convex bounded set and $f$ be an integrable function. It is well known that the Dirichlet problem for the Poisson equation

$\partial_ \bar{z} \partial_z u(z) = f (z)\quad \mbox{in} \quad \Omega\quad $ such that   $\quad u(z) = h(z) \quad on \quad \partial\Omega$

is uniquely solveable, where $\partial_z,~ \partial \bar{z}$ are cauchy Riemann operators.

Now my question:

Is
$\quad \partial_ \bar{z} \partial^2_z u(z) = f (z)\quad \mbox{in} \quad \Omega\quad $ such that   $\quad u(z) = h(z) \quad on \quad \partial\Omega\quad$ uniquely solveable?

My attempt:

Let $\partial_z u(z) = w (z),$ then we have the system of equations
$$\partial_z u(z) = w (z)\quad \mbox{in} \quad \Omega \quad \mbox{such that} \quad u(z) = h(z) \quad on \quad \partial\Omega$$

and

$$\partial_ \bar{z} \partial_z w(z) = f (z)\quad \mbox{in} \quad \Omega\quad \mbox{such that}   \quad w(z) = ? \quad on \quad \partial\Omega.$$

The first equation is solvable by the Cauchy Pompieu Formula, while the second is solvable if we can determine the boundary condition. How do I continue from here? Thanks.

Comment: You need boundary condition on $w(z)$

Comment: By $\partial\bar{z}$ do you mean $\partial_{\bar{z}}$?

Comment: Yes, its the Cauchy Riemmann operator

Comment: Can the condition be: $w(z)=\partial_z h$?

Comment: @Mary shortly -- yes, it's very broad question

Comment: Are $u(z), f(z),$ etc. analytic functions? If not, I suggest that you write $u(z,\bar{z}), f(z,\bar{z}),$ etc.

Comment: @Gonçalo we dont need that since we are working with the Cauchy  Riemann operators.